# GCC quais os casos de uso de: -static-libgcc e -export-dynamic?

Tags: c, gcc

Trabalho com a linguagem C e uso o compilador GCC, em alguns tutoriais vi o uso de:

- `-static-libgcc`
- `-export-dynamic`

Mas não sei por quê e nem quando usá-los e para que servem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do GCC no capitulo [Opções de Vinculação(Options for Linking)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) tanto as opções
`-shared-libgcc` e `-static-libgcc` são opções de uso do compilador GCC que controlam como será feita a vinculação da biblioteca de baixo nível do GCC.
A maioria das rotinas `libgcc` lidam com operações aritméticas que o processador de destino não pode executar diretamente. Isso inclui multiplicação e divisão de inteiros em alguns processadores e todas as operações de ponto flutuante e de ponto fixo em outros processadores.
A `libgcc` também inclui rotinas para tratamento de exceções e um punhado de operações diversas.

Segue uma tradução livre da documentação GCC:

> `-shared-libgcc`
> `-static-libgcc`
> Em sistemas que fornecem a
> [libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html) como uma biblioteca compartilhada, essas opções forçam o
> uso da versão compartilhada ou estática, respectivamente. Se nenhuma
> versão compartilhada da `libgcc` foi compilado quando o compilador foi
> configurado, essas opções não têm efeito.
>
> Existem várias situações em que um aplicativo deve usar a `libgcc`
> compartilhada em vez da versão estática. O mais comum é quando o
> aplicativo deseja lançar e capturar exceções em diferentes bibliotecas
> compartilhadas. Nesse caso, cada uma das bibliotecas, bem como o
> próprio aplicativo, deve usar a `libgcc` compartilhada.
>
> Portanto, o driver G++ adiciona automaticamente a opção
> `-shared-libgcc` sempre que você cria uma biblioteca compartilhada ou
> um executável principal, porque os programas C++ normalmente usam
> exceções, então essa é a coisa certa a fazer.
>
> Se, em vez disso, você usar o driver GCC para criar bibliotecas
> compartilhadas, poderá descobrir que elas nem sempre estão vinculadas
> a `libgcc` compartilhada. Se o GCC descobrir, no momento da
> configuração, que você tem um linker não GNU ou um linker GNU que não
> suporta a opção `--eh-frame-hdr`, esse vincula a versão compartilhada
> do `libgcc` em bibliotecas compartilhadas por padrão. Caso contrário,
> ele aproveita o linker e otimiza a vinculação com a versão
> compartilhada do `libgcc`, vinculando com a versão estática do
> `libgcc` por padrão. Isso permite que as exceções se propaguem por
> meio dessas bibliotecas compartilhadas, sem incorrer em custos de
> realocação no tempo de carregamento da biblioteca.
>
> No entanto, se uma biblioteca ou executável principal deve lançar ou
> capturar exceções, você deve vinculá-lo usando o driver G++ ou usando
> a opção `-shared-libgcc`, de modo que esteja vinculado a libgcc
> compartilhada.

As opções `-export-dynamic` e `--no-export-dynamic` são por vez opções do [Linker](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligador).
Essas opções são passadas para o [`ld`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) que combina vários objetos e arquivos, realocando os seus dados e vinculando referências a símbolos. Normalmente, o último passo na compilação de um programa é executar o `ld`.

Segue uma tradução livre da documentação `ld`:

> `--export-dynamic`
> `--no-export-dynamic`
>
> Ao criar um executável vinculado dinamicamente, usar a opção `-E` ou a
> opção `--export-dynamic` faz com que o linker adicione todos os
> símbolos à [tabela de símbolos dinâmicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table). A tabela de símbolos
> dinâmicos é o conjunto de símbolos que são visíveis a partir de
> objetos dinâmicos em tempo de execução. Se você não usar nenhuma
> dessas opções (ou usar a opção `--no-export-dynamic` para restaurar o
> comportamento padrão), a tabela de símbolos dinâmicos normalmente
> conterá apenas os símbolos referenciados por algum objeto dinâmico
> mencionado na vinculação.
>
> Se você usar [`dlopen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) para carregar um objeto dinâmico que
> precisa se referir aos símbolos definidos pelo programa, em vez de
> algum outro objeto dinâmico, provavelmente precisará usar essa opção
> ao vincular o próprio programa.
>
> Você também pode usar a lista dinâmica para controlar quais símbolos
> devem ser adicionados à tabela de símbolos dinâmicos se o formato de
> saída for compatível. Veja a descrição de [`--dynamic-list`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld#:%7E:text=support%20shared%20libraries.-,%2D%2Ddynamic%2Dlist,-%3Ddynamic%2Dlist) .
>
> Observe que esta opção é específica para [executáveis ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). Os
> [executáveis PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) suportam uma função semelhante para
> exportar todos os símbolos de uma DLL ou EXE ; veja a descrição de
> [`--export-all-symbols`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld#:%7E:text=of%20the%20linker%5D-,%2D%2Dexport%2Dall%2Dsymbols,-If%20given%2C%20all).